# Having trouble converting variable to factor for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to plot data from the `nycflights13` data set. I want `month` and `dep_delay` variable to be factors rather than continuous. I am getting a error with no explanation and am stuck. Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)
f <- group_by(flights, month) %>%
summarise(delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
ggplot(mutate(month = as.factor(unlist(month))) + 
geom_bar(aes(month, delay, fill=month),stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do the mutate inside the `ggplot` call like that. It does not get properly parsed inside, as the ggplot call gets the data, but cannot carry out the mutate step.
Do it in an outside call:

```
f <- group_by(flights, month) %>%
  summarise(delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(month = as.factor(month)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(month, delay, fill=month),stat = "identity")
```